# How to match everything between two comma's if there is a match between the same two comma's?

Tags: regex

I have this string..

```
aa reddit down,spectrum new,comcast outage,sa discord park,asd reddit news,
```

And this piece of regex..

```
(?<=,|^|\s)discord(?=,|$|\s).+?(?=,)
```

..matches the following

```
discord park
```

while i want it to match this..

```
sa discord park
```

So in general want two match all characters between two comma's in a string if there is a match between the same two comma's.

This looks scary, but I've put the previous regular expression next to each other twice and put a `|` in between. This is an extra requirement for me to approve the answer because I want to be able to put multiple regular expressions next to each other.

```
(?<=,|^|\s)discord(?=,|$|\s).+?(?=,)|(?<=,|^|\s)reddit(?=,|$|\s).+?(?=,)
```

This would match..

`discord park` and `reddit news`

While want it to match..

`as discord park` and `asd reddit news`

Comment: Maybe you just want `[^,]*\bdiscord\b[^,]*`? See https://regex101.com/r/JBH1HV/1. Expanding to one or more words, `[^,]*\b(?:reddit|discord)\b[^,]*`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I can not directly come up with a scenario where `(?<=,|^)[^,]*` is different from `[^,]*` That means your pattern would be the better choice.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am learning Regex by reading Mastering Regex and I am at chapter 1 right now. I have written this regex [a-z]+ +(reddit|discord) [a-z]+, which seems to work but do you think its a valid regex?

Comment: It is a valid regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might use a negated character class with an alternation for both words:

```
(?<=,|^)[^,]*\b(?:reddit|discord)\b[^,]*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/97MxKF/1)

Comment: You are amazing!

Comment: @Fabian Looking at Wiktor's comment, I think you can omit the positive lookbehind as well. So the pattern could be shortened to `[^,]*\b(?:reddit|discord)\b[^,]*` https://regex101.com/r/6pBTgA/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird I am learning Regex by reading Mastering Regex and I am at chapter 1 right now. I have written this regex [a-z]+ +(reddit|discord) [a-z]+, which seems to work but do you think its a valid regex?

Comment: @KamranPervaiz Yes is it a valid regex, I also think it is a nice book.